# How make use of a coded Access database once

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

how can I improve coding structure, when there are a number of subs, functions using the same number of lines each time to make,open and close a connection to an Access database?

Can the lines of code to make and add a connection to the Access database be enclosed in one function and then called through function x () each time it needs to be used?

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated, thank you

can anyone also advise on other good coding structures or websites/tutorials that I could use? thank you

Comment: The fact is, with a Jet/ACE data store, you should likely be using a single persistent connection, rather than opening/closing the connection when you use it. The reason for this is that creating the locking file is a very expensive proposition. A persistent connection is the way Access works. I see you list ASP.NET as a tag, which suggests a web server environment. That's a terrible environment for using Jet/ACE and you should probably look for a more appropriate data store.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can and I actually advise you to do it.

Some simple yet powerfull advice on coding

- If you reuse the same lines of code at multiple places, then do put them in a sub(or function) and call the sub when needed.
- If some lines of codes are really similar in a lot of places and differs by small things (a number for example), then do put them in a sub(or function) with arguments and call the sub when needed.
- A sub(or function) should never have more than a few lines of codes. There are no real limit, but if you can't see the whole function in one page, then it is most likely too long.
- A sub (or function) should usually do only one thing. If your sub perform multiple tasks, it will be hard to reuse and will most likely span on more than one page.
- You might have heard this a lot before, but use meaningfull variable and function names! var1,i,x,textbox1 and the others are only goods for iterating (for i = 0 to 10).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you David for your reply, I also meant to ask about classes and objects - how can these be used within asp.net (vb.net)? I have not been able to grasp the concept of how to use classes&objects within asp.net but I can most definitely take on board and use the suggestions you have made, thanks

Comment: The only difference between coding for ASP.net and 'normal' windows client application is the GUI, all the code behind is pretty much the same. So you can define classes and objects as you would in a windows client application.